# Request method 'POST' not supported error spring boot and ajax. But GET does not have the same error

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, post, httprequest

Sorry for asking repeated question but I have tried many solutions but none works,

So I have this class and table **Draft**, in the index.html I have a table containing many data, I want to use **ajax** to pass all of that data to **Controller** class in back-end to save that data in the draft table in the database which equivalent to class Draft.

But this error happened Request method 'POST' not supported.

The problem is GET does not return this error and I want to use POST to pass data.

This is my Draft controller class

```
@Controller
@Secured({"ADMIN","SUPER_ADMIN"})
public class DraftController {
    @Autowired
    private DraftService draftService;

    @PostMapping("/newdraft")
    public @ResponseBody Draft AddDraft(@RequestBody Draft draft, BindingResult result) {
        draftService.save(draft); // save the draft to database
        return draft;
    }

}
```

This is my ajax function

```
$("#draftFormSubmit").on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        call_draft();
    });
    
    function call_draft() {
                 var draft = {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id":5,
            "lowest_cost_found":3,
            "paper_used":3,
            "print_type":3,
            "actual_ups_per_paper":3,
            "quantity":3,
            "color":3,
            "size":3,
            "gloss_lam":3,
            "matt_lam":3,
            "water_based":3,
            "uv":3,
            "varnish":3,
            "spot_uv":3,
            "emboss_deboss":3,
            "hot_stamping":3,
            "diecut":3,
            "creasing_line":3,
            "total_price":3,
            "markup":3,
            "final_price":3
            }
            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/newdraft",
            data: JSON.stringify(draft),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Only in this project the error occurs, when I write a simple POST on another project it does not have this error.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")  // <------------
@Secured({"ADMIN","SUPER_ADMIN"})
public class DraftController {
```

and check again

Comment: still not working :((